# prove that any non decreasing function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [a,b]$ must have a fixed point .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

prove that any non decreasing function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [a,b]$ must have a fixed point .

My work : Assume no fixed point exists .Take any $c\in [a,b] $ and $b_n=f^n(c)$ for $n=0,1... $ . Clealr $b_n$ is increasing sequence and bounded by $b$ . So $\lim b_n= sup (b_n) =l\in [a,b] $ . So $b_n \leq l $ . So $f(b_n)<f(l) $ Hence $l=sup (f(b_n))\leq f(l)$ . So we have got a point $l \in [a,b] $  such $ f(l)\geq l$ . It will be sufficient to prove $f(l)\leq l$ . Then we will done . But i'm not sure if this true . 
Help needed . Thank you

Comment: $b_n$ is not clearly an increasing sequence, in actual fact it is possible for it to be a decreasing sequence. Consider $f(x) = x^2$ on [0,1], which is a non decreasing function on this interval, and take the point $c =0.1$, then clearly $b_n = f^n(0.1)$ is a decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG you can consider $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$. Let $I =[0, a)$ is maximal half-interval such that $f(x)>x, x \in I$. Consider 3 cases:

1. $f(a)>a$. In this case $a \neq 1$. Let $\varepsilon=f(a)-a$ and let $I'=[a, a+ \frac\varepsilon2)$. If $x \in I'$ then $f(x) \ge f(a)=a+\varepsilon > x$, contradiction.
2. $f(a)<a$. In this case $a \neq 0$. Let $\varepsilon=a-f(a)$ and let $I''=[a- \frac\varepsilon2, a]$. If $x \in I''$ then $f(x) \le f(a)=a-\varepsilon < x$, contradiction.
3. Therefore, $f(a)=a$, QED.

Added for completeness: $a+ \frac\varepsilon2 = a + \frac{f(a)-a}{2}=\frac{f(a)+a}{2}<f(a) \leq 1$ and similarly $a- \frac\varepsilon2 = a - \frac{a -f(a)}{2}=\frac{a+f(a)}{2} > 0$, so $f$ is defined on both $I'$ and $I''$.

Update: It is interesting, that if $f$ is non-increasing then the statement if false. Indeed, let $g(x)=1-x, 0 \leq x < \frac12$, and $g(x)=0, \frac12 \leq x  \leq 1$. It is easy to check that $g(x)\neq x, x\in[0,1]$.